# Pass a list of tuples into Sum

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, summation

I have a function of two arguments, `f[x_,y_]`, and I want to sum the value of this function for a number of input tuples `{x,y}` which are in a list. I don't see any way of doing this with `Sum`. I could write a loop but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

Edit:

Specifically, my function is actually a matrix where the elements are determined by `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) function `f`:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x + y)^2;
a = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}};

f @@@ a
(* {9, 25, 49, 81, 121} *)

f @@@ a // Total
(* 285 *)
```

Comment: sorry i should have clarified, what if my function is a matrix of functions? Say,

`f[x_,y_] = {{a[x,y],b[x,y]},{c[x,y],d[x,y]}}`

Comment: @Kai It will still work. The result will just be a matrix with sum of elements.

Comment: Thanks, I was having another issue that was preventing it from working but I've got it now

Comment: I have a further question, what if my function is `f[x,y,A]`, where `A` is an extra vector of parameters? I want to be able to use this in a loop where each time the values in `A` are updated, but I always pass the same list to the `x,y` arguments

Comment: I found I can define `f[{x_,y_},A_]` then perform `f[#,Avalues]&/@tuples` which seems to work fine.